# How do a make an image zoomed in and not stretched when the screen is too large?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am using bootstrap 4 inside my wordpress theme. I am trying to make a slide show on the top of my page but the images are stretching out when the size is not 100%.

How do I make the images zoom instead of stretching. I have tried applying

```
.cover {
    background-position: center center !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-attachment: fixed !important;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

class to my  tag.

This is the code for where I want to add the image.

```html
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img class='cover' src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/incl/1.jpg');?>">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>Voorbeeld 1</h3>
    <p>Voorbeeld beskrywing</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img class='cover' src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/incl/2.jpg');?>" >
    <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>Voorbeeld 2</h3>
    <p>Voorbeeld beskrywing</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img class='cover' src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/incl/3.jpg');?>">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>Voorbeeld 3</h3>
    <p>Voorbeeld beskrywing.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you can provide something more in terms of the styles which currently are associated with your slider, it would better help understand the problem. A live test link would be the best to help you out as there could be a number of reasons why your styles are not working. In theory, what you have should span your slider image as you have background-size: cover in there.

Comment: Hi, I am using bootstrap 4. I got the classes from here https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're expecting image source (`src`) to be treated as `background-image`.
Might be `!important` to you, but it won't happen.

You probably want to show the image as background of parent (I moved `cover` class on parent):

```css
.cover {
  background: transparent no-repeat fixed center /cover;
}

.cover img {
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover" style="background-image: url(https://loremflickr.com/620/240)">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/620/240">
  <div class="caption">
    <h1>Caption stuff here...</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.cover {
  background: transparent no-repeat fixed center /cover;
}

.cover img {
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
/* You don't need anything below this point. Just for SO example */
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.cover {
  position: relative;
}
.cover .caption{
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  background-color: #42424242;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff35;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 6px -3px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 9px 12px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.07), 0 3px 16px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.06) 
}
```

```html
<div class="cover" style="background-image: url(https://loremflickr.com/620/240)">
 <img src="https://loremflickr.com/620/240">
  <div class="caption">
    <h1>Caption stuff here...</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

This lets the `<img>` still set the height of the slide but won't show it, so the background can be viewed. Obviously, you need to do it for each of the items.